# Passing certain form values over with a POST

Tags: javascript, ajax

What i am trying to do is, once my form is submitted, it will pass certain values from a form to PayPal.

This is my form code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form class="form-horizontal" action="<?php echo whichPPUrl(); ?>" method="post" id="paypal_form" target="_blank">

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-xs-4" for="text">URL:</label> 
    <div class="col-xs-8">
      <input id="text" name="url" placeholder="site.com" type="text" class="form-control" required="required">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">

    <label class="control-label col-xs-4" for="checkbox">&nbsp;</label> 
    <div class="col-xs-8">
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label class="checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" class="sum" name="metrics_1" value="1.00">
              <strong>Moz</strong> - DA/PA/MozRank/Links In/Equity
        </label>
      </div>

      <div class="checkbox">
        <label class="checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" class="sum" name="metrics_2" value="1.00">
              <strong>SEMRush</strong> - Rank/Keywords Number/Traffic/Costs/URL Links Number/Hostname Links Number/Domain Links Number
        </label>
      </div>

      <div class="checkbox">
        <label class="checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" class="sum" name="metrics_3" value="1.00">
              <strong>Majestic</strong> - Rank/Keywords Number/Traffic/Costs/URL Links Number/Hostname Links Number/Domain Links Number
        </label>
      </div>

      <div class="checkbox">
        <label class="checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" class="sum" name="metrics_4" value="1.00">
              <strong>Backlinks</strong> - Get any backlinks found for your domain plus anchor text (250 max.)
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="total" class="control-label col-xs-4">Cost ($):</label> 
    <div class="col-xs-8">
      <input id="total" name="cost" type="text" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="total" class="control-label col-xs-4">&nbsp;</label> 
    <div class="col-xs-8">
      <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick" />
      <input type="hidden" name="business" value="contact@site.co.uk">
      <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Wraith Metrics">
      <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="1">
      <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
      <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="getTheFormValues()">
      <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="getAndPassTheCost()">
      <input type="hidden" name="return" value="https://www.wraithseo.com/custom-metrics-builder.php?paid=1">
      <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="https://www.wraithseo.com/gateway/ipn.php">
      <input type="image" src="images/purchase.png" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</form>

<script>
    // pass the total value over to the form: <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="getTheCost()">
    function getAndPassTheCost() {
        return $("#total").val();
    }
</script>   

<script>
    // pass the form values over and deal with them on the backend: <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="getTheFormValues()">
    function getTheFormValues() {
        return $("form").serialize();
    }
</script>   

<script>    
$(document).ready(function() {
    // updates / adds the checkbox values
    function updateSum() {
      var total = "0.00";
      $(".sum:checked").each(function(i, n) {
         let sum = parseFloat(total) + parseFloat($(n).val());
         total = sum.toFixed(2);
      });
      $("#total").val(total);
    }
    // run the update on every checkbox change and on startup
    $("input.sum").change(updateSum);
    updateSum();
});
</script>
```

I am not the greatest with Ajax, i have done a basic example of what i think is the right way to go:

This function:

```
<script>
    // pass the total value over to the form: <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="getTheCost()">
    function getAndPassTheCost() {
        return $("#total").val();
    }
</script>
```

Would get the value from the input text box and pass it through to the post form.

This function:

```
<script>
    // pass the form values over and deal with them on the backend: <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="getTheFormValues()">
    function getTheFormValues() {
        return $("form").serialize();
    }
</script>
```

Would just serialize all the form data which i can then validate and process on the backend.

Have i over complicated the process? my issue is i'm not able to pass this data to the form whcih is then sent via POST to a PayPal script, any help in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: One thing that needs to happen is to change the hidden fields that have JavaScript functions as values.  That won't work.  If you change those hidden fields to text fields, you will see the value is the name of the function.  One thing you can do is wire up the click event of your submit button to run those functions and pass the values into your hidden fields.  And by the way, where is your submit button?

Answer (score 0):

The inputs can only store strings they cannot store functions. Assign values to form controls by the `.val()` method. The functions `getAndPassTheCost()` and `getTheFormValues()` are useless. If you need to serialize the form, do it during the submit event. As for collecting all of the form values, that is done at submit event -- just ensure that whatever values you want sent has a `[name]` attribute.

**Demo will send to a live test server -- the response will be displayed in the iframe below.**

```js
function updateSum() {
  var total = 0;
  $(".sum:checked").each(function(i) {
    let sum = parseFloat($(this).val());
    total += sum;
  });
  $("#total, .total").val(total.toFixed(2));
}

$("input.sum").on('change', updateSum);
$('paypal_form').on('submit', function(e) {
  $(this).serialize();
});
```

```css
.line.line.line {
  margin: -5px auto 5px
}

.img.img.img {
  margin: -40px auto 0 -70px;
}

.img.img.img:focus {
  outline: none
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<main class='container'>
  <form class="form-horizontal" action="https://httpbin.org/post" method="post" id="paypal_form" target="response">

    <section class='form-row'>
      <fieldset class='form-group col'>
        <legend>Wraith SEO</legend>
        <input id="text" name="url" placeholder="site.com" type="text" class="form-control" required pattern='[a-z0-9]+?[.][a-z]{3,}'>
      </fieldset>
    </section>

    <hr class='line'>

    <section class='form-row'>
      <div class='form-group col'>
        <div class="form-check-inline">
          <label class="form-check-label">
  <input type="checkbox" class="sum form-check-input" name="metrics_1" value="1.00"> 1.00</label></div>

        <div class="form-check-inline">
          <label class="form-check-label">
  <input type="checkbox" class="sum form-check-input" name="metrics_2" value="1.00"> 1.00</label></div>

        <div class="form-check-inline">
          <label class="form-check-label">
  <input type="checkbox" class="sum form-check-input" name="metrics_3" value="1.00"> 1.00</label></div>

        <div class="form-check-inline">
          <label class="form-check-label">
  <input type="checkbox" class="sum form-check-input" name="metrics_4" value="1.00"> 1.00</label></div>

        <label for='total' class="label-control">Total: $ 
        <output id='total' value='0.00'> </output></label>

        <input class='total' name='total' type='hidden' value=''>
      </div>
    </section>

    <section class='form-row'>
      <fieldset class='form-group mb-4'>
        <input type="image" src="https://www.shareicon.net/data/128x128/2017/06/22/887585_logo_512x512.png" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!" class='float-right img'>

        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
        <input type="hidden" name="business" value="contact@site.co.uk">
        <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Wraith Metrics">
        <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="1">
        <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
        <input type="hidden" name="return" value="https://www.wraithseo.com/custom-metrics-builder.php?paid=1">
        <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="https://www.wraithseo.com/gateway/ipn.php">

        <iframe name='response' width='70%' class='float-left'></iframe>
      </fieldset>
    </section>
  </form>

</main>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```